# How to detect if a text-field needs to wrap in JavaScript/dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a textfield in a grid in which I wish to turn off text wrapping, but display a tooltip with the full text if wrapping is required. So, how could I detect if a field needs to wrap?

I tried to query the field's length, but it was either in `em` or in `px` based on if the user resized it. How could I get the wrapping status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option to detect if the text wraps - create (with jQuery, for instance) an invisible span with the same font settings and `white-space: nowrap`, set it's `text` to the field's content and check if the span's width is bigger than the field's width (in pixels, obtained via `width()`)

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TR98y/1/

Comment: The fiddle updated to reflect your exact scenario - having an overflow on the textarea and setting the title

Comment: Oh, yes! It works for me!
I was able to adapt your suggestion to suit my needs.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can check the height (via scrollHeight) of the text container. It should increase when things start wrapping.

The only other alternative I can think of is setting overflow-x:hidden and then dettecting the overflow somehow.